# Javascript multiple script tag are allowed?

Tags: javascript

I have an html file where I see two javascript tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var varname = .... etc
</script>

<script language ="JavaScript">

 function namefunction . . . etc

</script>
```

is this allowed? Or can create issue with loading js in the page?

Comment: muliple script tags are allowed in an html.

Comment: why are you all voting down the post? At least provide a reason to improve! Not acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in using multiple Script in html.
How it is loaded is depending on which on the order it is added into the html.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally allowed. It shouldn't cause any issues whatsoever.